# Excel.Shape throwing ArgumentException

Tags: vb.net, vsto, excel-interop

I have a class which wraps an `Excel.Shape`.

In one of my functions (which allows to move the shape from one sheet to another), I have the following code:

```
Private Property ThisShape As Excel.Shape

Public Property Sheet As Excel.Worksheet Implements IShapeWrapper.Sheet
    Get
        If Not Me.HasShape Then Return Nothing
        Return Me._Sheet
    End Get
    Set(value As Excel.Worksheet)

        If value Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(value))
        If Not Me.HasShape Then Exit Property 'Throw New InvalidOperationException("Unable to assign sheet: This wrapper does not contain any shapes.")
        If value Is Me._Sheet Then Exit Property

        Try
            Dim TestShapeName As Excel.Shape = value.Shapes.Item(Me.ThisShape.Name)
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("The destination worksheet already contains a shape with the same name.")
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        Me._Sheet = value

        VBMath.Randomize()
        Dim ShapeNamePrefix As String = $"AppName_{CInt(VBMath.Rnd() * 1000000)}_{Date.Now.Millisecond}_"
        Dim TempName As String = ShapeNamePrefix & Me.ThisShape.Name
        Me.ThisShape.Name = TempName
        Me.ThisShape.Cut()
        value.Paste()

        Me.ThisShape = Nothing
        For Each MyShape As Excel.Shape In value.Shapes
            If MyShape.Name = TempName Then
                Me.ThisShape = MyShape
                MyShape.Name = String.Concat(MyShape.Name.Skip(ShapeNamePrefix.Length))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If Me.ThisShape Is Nothing Then Throw New ApplicationException("Unable to re-bind with shape after copy/pasting.")

    End Set
End Property
Private _Sheet As Excel.Worksheet
```

For some shapes (actually, always the same one, which is one amongst 50 shapes I am processing),

`MyShape.Name = String.Concat(MyShape.Name.Skip(ShapeNamePrefix.Length))` throws on `MyShape`

> System.ArgumentException: The specified value is out of range.

It is quite confusing because the line basically does `MyObject.Property = MyObject.Property & Something`. When debugging, I am able to echo `?MyShape.Name` (which anyways has just been read 2 lines above in the code)

I am confused as to what this exception refers to (is it unable to locate the shape by index?), and why assigning the property fails.

This is VB.Net code, but I added the VBA tag as I suspect this is an Office.Interop API issue.

Comment: What is different about that one shape compared to the other shapes?

Comment: I still have not figured out..! They are all wrapped and manipulated by the same objects..

Comment: What are the actual string values of `MyShape.Name` for a Shape that works and for the one that does not work?

Comment: You can get that error if `ShapeNamePrefix.Length` is greater than `MyShape.Name`. Debug the values and see if this is true for this shape. It's equivalent to say, `shp.Name = Mid("Sid", 6, 5)` in VBA

Comment: All shapes had same length (mixture of GUID and keywords). Problem solved, it was because that specific shape was `Locked`. Interesting and confusing: how on earth one can copy/paste but not rename a shape when locked, and how does `out of range` translate to `property is locked`? ...

Answer (score 0):

If a shape is protected, it can be moved programmatically, but it cannot be renamed. Just like it is possible to programmatically change cell contents of a protected sheet, whilst merging/unmerging cells requires to unprotect the sheet.

The fix is to either untick the `protected` box in the shape properties (or via the [Interop API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shape.locked?view=excel-pia)), or to unlock the sheet itself.